# go_router - Is there a way to push twice the same page?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I'm using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to build an application that
does "dummy" pushes of routes (a bit like Twitter). It is possible to start with a page `/a` ,push `/b`, then `/c`, ... and then push again `/a`.

When a page is pushed twice, an `assert` fails: `assert(!keyReservation.contains(key));` which ensures a key is used only once in the `Navigator`.

Is there a way to be able to push twice the same page with go_router?

Here is a small code snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/a',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/a',
      builder: (_, __) => const MyWidget(path: '/a'),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/b',
      builder: (_, __) => const MyWidget(path: '/b'),
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    required this.path,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String path;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(path),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.push('/a');
            },
            child: const Text('/a'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.push('/b');
            },
            child: const Text('/b'),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue can be triggered by clicking on the `TextButton` with "/a".

Comment: in the init state(){} you can recall the self state

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin, `initState` of what widget? And do you mean `setState` ?

Comment: no   @override
  void initState() { }  this

Comment: this question is helper for you [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448943/go-router-flutter-push-the-exact-same-route-and-refresh-that-route)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a bug in go_router (see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107045)) which has been solved in the version [`4.2.3`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#423).

So now you should be able to push the same page twice.