# Navigate to a page and reload the page using go router flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-go-router

I am navigating from home to test screen using flutter `gorouter` like this.. from a button in modal bottom sheet in homescreen:

```
context.pushNamed(
Destination.viewSingleTest,
extra: test
);
```

Now in test screen after completion, I want to go back to home screen while reloading the content/screen.

```
context.go(Destination.bottomNav);
```

Problem is:

It doesn't reload the page, it just goes back to the modal sheet been opened in the home screen.

I want to go to that page and reload the screen

Comment: This issue is a duplicate of the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448943/go-router-flutter-push-the-exact-same-route-and-refresh-that-route)